# BottomNavigationView getting placed on top of parent

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im using BottomNavigationView built into AndroidStudio and im trying to place this on the bottom of the parent. I am using layout_gravity="bottom", but it still gets moved to the top. Any ideas on what im doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">


        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/profil"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: https://gyazo.com/a793e7f5390bc521a26b8f6dc621e54d]

Comment: The RelativeLayout should occupy all the other space between your image and the BottomNavigationView? Also, you could use a ConstraintLayout so you can sen the view to the bottom of your layout

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, an alternative is to use `ConstraintLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/profil" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This pushes the image out of the screen at the top

Comment: You are right, i've edited the post, `android:layout_marginBottom="750dp"` is not necesary